# Getting substring from a string after and before particular characters

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string of some random length (not specified as requirement).

Example:

```
dev.ca.ind.clientaddress-completed-events.dom.0.ind-isl-clientaddress-completed.dlq
```

Here, I have to skip three strings, i.e. `dev.ca.ind.` (I want what is after these strings and before this) `.dom`, i.e. `clientaddress-completed-events` (I want to fetch this string from that whole string)

Second example:

```
dev.ca.ind.insurance.client.insurance.dom.0
```

I want to fetch `insurance.client.insurance` after `ind` and before `dom` and also this `ind` can also be `gb`,`grs`,`all`,`ind`. And `dom` can also be `raw`,`cdc`.

How do I do this? I am unable to get idea on how to do this.

I have tried splitting these string with "." but pattern is different for some string as shown in example and this is creating some bugs, so I thought of this way, but wasn't able to implement.

```
String[] splitName = topics.get(PROJECT+i).get(TOPIC_NAME).split("\\.");
```

but it was not good as I have to assign substrings using hardcoded index values, e.g. `ss.set(splitName[2]+splitName[3])`.

Some more examples:

```
dev.ca.xfunc.cxo.rawleads.dom.0 - get "cxo.rawleads"
dev.ca.epm.ceapm.zab.dom.0 - get "ceapm.zab"
dev.ca.ind.cx.talas.cdc.0 - get "cx.talas"
dev.ca.cif.source-system-client.dom.0 -get "source-system-client"

dev.ca.gb.claim.providers.int.0 -get "claim.providers"
```

Comment: Just iterate through the string (or use `indexOf`) while keeping track how many `.` you have already encountered, then save the start and end index you need for the call to `substring` - that shouldn't be more than a few lines of code to do

Comment: yes you are correct but the problem is after 3 dots(.) the name starts and in some cases there is (.) present in names also, so by this it would be difficult to determine the name. I have added some more examples. i need something like after 3 dots and before dom/cdc/int.

Comment: That doesn't really make it that much more complicated, you just need to have a different condition to find the end index after you found the first 3 dots for the start index. So then you'd continue iterating until you find one of `.dom`/`.cdc`/whatever else you use as delimiter

Comment: Thanks @UnholySheep I used your approach with Bentaye approach of suffix, I think it can work now I just have to run some test cases.

Answer (score 0):

remove `dev.ca.` then everything up to the next dot, included:

```
private static String removePrefix(String s) {
    String noPrefix = s.substring(7); // remove `dev.ca.`
    return noPrefix.substring(noPrefix.indexOf('.')+1);
}
```

Then get the substring of the remaining string up to one the expected end token:

```
private static String removeSuffix(String s) {
    return Stream.of(".dom.", ".raw.", ".cdc.", ".int.")
            .filter(s::contains)
            .findFirst()
            .map(p -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf(p)))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Invalid String '" + s + "' - suffix not found"));
}
```

and do

```
removeSuffix(removePrefix(s))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks I used your approach of remove suffix. but removePrefix is not working in any case it is throwing invalid String exception. And also there is a case for suffix `dev.ca.xfunc.cxo.rawleadsintake.dom.0` where it is reading `.raw in .rawleadsintake` and giving string as `dev.ca.xfunc.cxo` is there some way to ignore `rawleadsintake` ?  And also prefix can be anything before 3rd(.) dot so if you can please modify removePrefix. I want data after 3rd dot

Comment: @Aashi updated, have a try

Answer (score -1):

If it were me, I would use the split function that returns an array of elements like so:

```
String target = "dev.ca.ind.clientaddress-completed-events.dom.0.ind-isl-clientaddress-completed.dlq"    
String keyTokens = target.split(".")
```

That will give you a keyTokens array of items like so:
"dev"
"ca"
"ind"
"clientaddress-completed-events"
"dom"
"0"
"ind-isl-clientaddress-completed"
"dlq"

Then walk the array looking for the first String where "isInteger" returns true.

Comment: `target.split(.)` won't do what you think it does (it will return an empty array). `split` takes a regular expression, nor does it return a single string, but a string array.

Comment: I have done this, i want to make my code more generic and also split will give you array instead of single string. btw thanks for the effort but this didn't help.

Comment: If you want to make it more generic then you're going to have to use a Regular expression.  I gave you a brute force way that will work.